# How to open GUI from systemd service on startup?

Tags: services, display, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to start a VMWare Workstation VM from the command line. I can do this under my user (not `root`) by running the following

```bash
/usr/bin/vmplayer /home/myUser/vmware/myVm.vmx
```

Now, I want to set this VM to start on boot, so I created a service  `/lib/systemd/system/myService.service` with the following:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=my vm service

[Service]
User=myUser
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vmplayer /home/myuser/vmware/myVm.vmx
Environment=DISPLAY=:0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I run the service from the terminal (i.e. `sudo systemctl restart myService`) I can see the VM window popping up and starting correctly. However, if I reboot the system the VM doesn't start and this is the `status` I get

```
Jan 23 12:55:59 home systemd[1]: Started myService service.
Jan 23 12:56:00 home truenas.sh[848]: [AppLoader] Use shipped Linux kernel AIO access library.
Jan 23 12:56:00 home truenas.sh[848]: An up-to-date "libaio" or "libaio1" package from your system is preferred.
Jan 23 12:56:00 home vmplayer[848]: cannot open display: :0
Jan 23 12:56:00 home systemd[1]: myService.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 23 12:56:00 home systemd[1]: myService.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I thought `DISPLAY=:0` on the environment would fix the issue but that's the error I got and I'm not able to fix it.

Comment: You are installing as a system service so there is no display. You could try installing as a user service -- this will start when you login. Assuming a local login you will have a display. Alternatively you could try running your vm 'headless'. VirtualBox has this option, don't know about VMWare.

Comment: I set it up as a user service but I get the same error. Very strange because if I just restart the service manually it works...

Comment: Do you have the desktop file for `VMWare`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Stephen Boston pointed out in the comments you should use a systemd user service but you have to change, remove and add some directives in your unit:

1. Change: `WantedBy=multi-user.target` to `WantedBy=graphical-session.target`
2. Add the directives: `PartOf=graphical-session.target` and `After=graphical-session.target` in `[Unit]` section.
3. Add in `[Service]` the directive: `Type=exec`
4. You can remove `Environment=DISPLAY=:0`
5. May be you want to add also this directive in `[Service]` section: `Restart=no`

So your unit would become:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=my vm service
PartOf=graphical-session.target
After=graphical-session.target

[Service]
Type=exec
Restart=no
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vmplayer /home/myuser/vmware/myVm.vmx

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

Finally place the unit under: `$HOME/.config/systemd/user/` directory and to enable/start it you should use `systemctl --user ....`:

```bash
systemctl --user enable myService.service

systemctl --user start myService.service
```

---

You can also run apps on StartUp by using `.desktop` files and place them in `/etc/xdg/autostart` or in `~/.config/autostart`. Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/1086345) for more details.

Comment: The service part didn't work for me for some reason. It doesn't give me any information other than error code 1. However, I marked your answer as resolved, since I could start the VM from the Startup Application Preferences. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Victor Glad to know some solution worked. About the error you can use `journalctl --user -xeu myService.service` for a more detailed log (maybe it's something related to VMware dependencies). In my case I tested with Nautilus on Ubuntu server and worked successfully.