# Fail to run a systemd on Ubuntu

Tags: systemd

I need to run a script at every boot. For that, I've create a `.sh` file, which runs as needed using a terminal.

To make it run during boot, I followed [this](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/) tutorial.

`.sh` file:

```
#! /bin/bash

sub1="myHome/Messages"
sub2="myHome/log"
sub3="myHome/debug"
user="guy"
pass="kupelu9e"
mqtt_broker="192.168.2.100"

gnome-terminal --tab --title $sub1 -- mosquitto_sub -u $user -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t $sub1
gnome-terminal --tab --title $sub2 -- mosquitto_sub -u $user -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t $sub2
gnome-terminal --tab --title $sub3 -- mosquitto_sub -u $user -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t $sub3

gnome-terminal -- mosquitto_pub -u $user  -P $pass -h $mqtt_broker -t "myHome/All" -m "status"
```

Unit file

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs terminalwith MQTT subs
After=network.target auditd.service

[Service]
User=guy
WorkingDirectory=/home/guy
ExecStart=/bin/bash 123.sh
```

running the deamon yeild an error:

```
guy@desktop:~$ systemctl status mqtt_subs.service 
× mqtt_subs.service - Runs terminalwith MQTT subs
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mqtt_subs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-04-11 15:12:53 IDT; 10s ago
    Process: 5193 ExecStart=/bin/bash mqtts.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 5193 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 273ms

Apr 11 15:12:52 desktop systemd[1]: Started Runs terminalwith MQTT subs.
Apr 11 15:12:52 desktop bash[5195]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop bash[5197]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop bash[5199]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop bash[5201]: # Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop systemd[1]: mqtt_subs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 11 15:12:53 desktop systemd[1]: mqtt_subs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
guy@desktop:~$
```

To be sure that the `systemd` service runs and defined  OK - I modified `123.sh` into an echo to write into a file (meaning - a very simple task), I don't get any error.

Appreciate any help

Guy

Comment: `gnome-terminal` needs a graphical shell to run on, which won't be available at boot time. That's what the `Cannot open display` errors are about.

Comment: You should use **user services** with directives `PartOf=graphical-session.target and After=graphical-session.target` or  you can use  **Startup Applications** (like autostart app in `/etc/xdg/autostart`). Check [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/732870/414186)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing my success (with the help of @Edgar Magallon's comment)

**Stage 1- create a Unit file:**

```
[Unit] Description=Runs terminalwith MQTT subs 
PartOf=graphical-session.target 
After=graphical-session.target

[Service]
Type=exec 
WorkingDirectory=/home/guy 
ExecStart=/bin/bash mqtts.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical-session.target
```

**Stage 2- A user service:**

file placed in `/home/guy/.config/systemd/user/mqtt_subs.service`, including execution presmission (`chmod +x`)

**Stage 3- Start user service:**

```
systemctl --user enable mqtt_subs.service

systemctl --user start mqtt_subs.service
```