# systemd service runs on Ubuntu but fail to run on Raspbian (Debian)

Tags: systemd

After Succeeding creating a service subsribe MQTT topic, on boot, as shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/742661/fail-to-run-a-systemd-on-ubuntu),

When I tried it on my raspberry Pi, with the needed modification - service won't start.

`.sh` file in raspbian (since it is not `gnome-terminal` as in ubuntu):

```
#! /bin/bash
topic1="myHome/Messages"
topic2="myHome/log"
topic3="myHome/debug"

user="guy"
password="kupelu9e"
broker="192.168.2.100"


lxterminal --display=:0 --title=$topic1 --command="mosquitto_sub -h $broker -t $topic1 -u $user -P $password" &
lxterminal --display=:0 --title=$topic2 --command="mosquitto_sub -h $broker -t $topic2 -u $user -P $password" &
lxterminal --display=:0 --title=$topic3 --command="mosquitto_sub -h $broker -t $topic3 -u $user -P $password" &

lxterminal --display=:0 --command="mosquitto_pub -h $broker -t "myHome/All" -u $user -P $password -m "status""
```

What may be the reason for that ?

**Edit_1 OUTPUTS**

`systemctl --user status mqtt_sub.service` outputs:

```
 mqtt_sub.service - MQTT subscribtion on terminal
     Loaded: loaded (/home/guy/.config/systemd/user/mqtt_sub.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

`journalctl --user -xeu mqtt_sub.service' outputs:

```
guy@raspberry:~ $ journalctl  --user -xeu mqtt_sub.service
 Support: https://www.debian.org/support
 
 The unit UNIT has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
-- Boot a7010da460194e7394fa641e0165314c --
Apr 13 08:01:28 raspberry systemd[947]: Starting MQTT subscribtion on terminal...
 Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://www.debian.org/support
 
 A start job for unit UNIT has begun execution.
 
 The job identifier is 143.
Apr 13 08:01:28 raspberry systemd[947]: Started MQTT subscribtion on terminal.
 Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
 Defined-By: systemd
 Support: https://www.debian.org/support
 
 A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
```

Comment: Did you try to run that script manually to see it works? Is display available at the time the systemd starts th service?

Comment: @nobody of course. When starting the service all was ok

Comment: Show the output of `systemctl --user status mqtt_subs.service` and `journalctl --user -xeu mqtt_subs.service` or `journalctl --user -xu mqtt_subs.service`. the difference between `-xeu` and `-xu` is that `-xeu` will jump to the end of the journal logs (this is useful when you have  a huge amount of logs as well as is useful to see only the last logs)

Comment: @EdgarMagallon see EDIT_1 please

Comment: @guyd all seems to be correct. Not sure what's going on. Maybe the service `Type` directive is not the correct here (but I doubt it). Try using another type and see what happens

Comment: @EdgarMagallon which `Type`s would you recommend to start with ?

Comment: @guyd I talk about systemd service types, there several values for directive `Type` but they have different purposes, I'm not very expert on this topic so I may be wrong but AFAIK your systemd service should work with `Type=exec` (specially because in Ubuntu works), another service type I suppose you can use is: `Type=forking`. Anyways, if you want to know more about systemd service `Type`s you can read the manual by running this command: `man systemd.service`